# Basis for polynomials of degree k or lower

Tags: polynomials

Is there a simple way to show that $\{(x-i)^n(x+i)^{k-n}\}_{n=0,...,k}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}_k[x]$ (space of polynomials of degree $\le k$) for $k\ge 2$ even? And likewise that $\{(x+w)^n(x+w^2)^{k-n}\}_{n=0,...,k}$ is a basis, where $w$ is the third root of unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider $(x-a)^n(x-b)^{k-n}$ for $0\le n\le k$ where $a\ne b$. All we need
is to show these are linearly independent. Suppose then
$$\sum_{n=0}^kc_n(x-a)^n(x-b)^{k-n}=0$$
identically. Then for all $x\ne b$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^kc_n\left(\frac{x-a}{x-b}\right)^n=0.$$
But unless all the $c_n$ are zero, this equation can only have finitely
many solutions for $(x-a)/(x-b)$, and so for $x$. But $\Bbb C$ is an infinite field.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was simpler than I thought! :)